# How to use AttributedString with TextEditor?

Tags: swiftui

I am using `TextEditor` with the `String` type right now but I want to use `AttributedString` because I want to find every character that starts with a `#` symbol and mark it a different color using [range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3813128-range).

How can I use `AttributedString` with `TextEditor`?

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    @State private var text = AttributedString("")
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: text)
    }
}
```

returns to me `Cannot convert value of type 'AttributedString' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

Comment: SwiftUI's `TextEditor` doesn't support `AttributedString`s

Comment: Is there a way I can work around that or is there another view that would offer me multiline text capability? Eventually I also want to have embedded images and other content types as well. Not sure if there's a generic view.

Comment: You'd need to use `UITextView`

Answer (score 4):

As of now SwiftUI TextEditor doesn't support AttributedStrings, to work around this, you might consider using a UIViewRepresentable to wrap a UITextView

```
import SwiftUI

struct AttributedTextEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: AttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: AttributedTextEditor

        init(_ parent: AttributedTextEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.text = AttributedString(textView.attributedText)
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use it in your SwiftUI view like this:

```
AttributedTextEditor(text: $attributedText)
        .onChange(of: attributedText, perform: { value in
            detectMentions()
    })
```